# Replace String only if it is not present

Tags: python, string, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary, like this `{"view": object.get("view")}`. Let's say the value to be returned is `"Table"`.
I want to add "_string" to it only if it is not already present. So Table should be Table_string, but if it is already Table_string, then let it be.
For example `{"view": object.get(f"{self.view}_string")}`, but only if "_string" is not already present. How can I do that using python?

Comment: honestly I have never used pyspark, so I'm not suited to give you an answer. But that sounds like a trivial if/else case where you check if the value exists already? Maybe this [isin function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isin.html) would help?

Comment: I don't see any reference to Spark/ PySpark in the question. Spark has dataframes, columns RDDs,... You deal with dictionary. That's python's thing, not Spark's. You need a python function? Please make it clear, how all you said connects to Spark.

Comment: @ZygD you’re right! Corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it using when otherwise and regexp_replcae function in pyspark

```
df.withColumn("value",when(value=="Table",regexp_replace(col(value),"Table","table_String")).otherwise(col(value))
```